# T24 - core banking

Tags: banking, core-banking

I am getting below error in t24 when executing Auth Routine.

FATAL ERROR IN (SENSITIVE ROUTINES CALLED IN LOCAL RTNS

the error appears when the routine gets executed and completed.

i have also tried to call a mainline routine which post OFS,
the problem is the code gets executed successfully, the OFS response is also retured.
but when the routine gets end, it shows this error.

Answer (score 1):

I know some but wanna share everyone this issue was solved, please check below capture

[image]

Just add 1 line `SENSITIVITY = ''` after execute OFS.GLOBUS.MANAGER, all version routine when face this this issue we can do this way no need to create main routine.